# Access to i Series Spool files from Windows PC

Tags: odbc, oledb, ibm-midrange

I need a reliable connection to spool files (reports)  from PC to iSeries Navigator

I have Data Analytics software (Monarch) running on a Windows PC.  I need a reliable connection to iSeries Navigator running on an AS400 run Data Analytics models against the spooled reports on Navigator

I could use VBA code to manipulate AS400 macros to access or move data between the AS400 and the windows pc, if this is an easy process to access the AS400 data

Comment: This question is a little unclear. iSeries Navigator does not run on AS400, but on Windows. It is client that can display spool files on the AS400 server. It likely uses and API to get the data. Is that what you are after?

Comment: [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzaik/rzaikappobj.htm#appobj) is a link to some documentation, it is for C++, but it provides DLL and call information. Maybe you can convert that to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

1st post...I can't ask for further clarification of your issue due to no privileges.

Unless you're looking for a direct connection between Monarch and iSeries Navigator (not sure that's an option), you can view the output queue, then drag-n-drop the spool file to the desktop.

On IBM i Access Client Solutions (the iSeries Navigator successor), you right-click the desired spool file to download to the desktop as a pdf file (default) or a text file.

In either case, the file should then be available for a Monarch import.

That's how our end-users utilize the AS400 spool files with Monarch.

Comment: Hello Sector 3... Thanks for your reply.  It seems difficult to link Monarch to Navigator directly.  As there will be a recurring need to access 30 or 40 spooled reports in the Navigator "Printer Output" folder, do you have any code that can be built into a batch file or VBA script to ftp or download the print reports as text files to a PC folder?  Could share the code and I will update for my purpose... Many thanks in advance